# Add second IP to interface - Linux (Android)

Tags: networking, android

I have a local network setup as shown in the picture below
[image: Local network]

The bridge has a static IP set to 10.245.245.253/30. My Android device has an IP set to 172.17.2.200 via DHCP. If I change the interface IP settings to 10.245.245.254/30 it works.

But I want to have the DHCP IP settings but just add a **secondary IP address, or route to the interface**, so I can **access the network** and **access my bridge** at the same time.

I've tried this command, but it still doesn't work.

```
ip addr add 10.245.245.254/30 dev wlan0
```

This is my configuration.

```
130|shell@msm8916_64:/ # busybox ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop
    link/ether 76:0d:fc:b7:9d:4f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: sit0: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0a:f5:80:c2:50 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.2.245/24 brd 172.17.2.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.245.245.254/30 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20a:f5ff:fe80:c250/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: p2p0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:0a:f5:80:c2:50 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

shell@msm8916_64:/ # busybox ip route show
10.245.245.252/30 dev wlan0  src 10.245.245.254
172.17.2.0/24 dev wlan0  src 172.17.2.245  metric 304

shell@msm8916_64:/ # busybox traceroute 10.245.245.253
traceroute to 10.245.245.253 (10.245.245.253), 30 hops max, 38 byte packets
 1  172.17.2.1 (172.17.2.1)  12.263 ms  2.305 ms  2.102 ms
```

I can ping my own IP:

```
130|shell@msm8916_64:/ # ping 10.245.245.254
PING 10.245.245.254 (10.245.245.254) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.245.245.254: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.775 ms
64 bytes from 10.245.245.254: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.201 ms
```

Any ideas?

EDIT 1:
To clarify the big picture. The wireless bridge is the device I am developing. It will be a device that when you plug an ethernet cable in will provide wireless access to the network. I do not know anything about that network. This is why I disabled DHCP client on my wireless bridge, because I cannot be certain that the network I attach it to will have a working DHCP server.

I still want to have an IP address set to the wireless bridge because of the firmware updates. This is why I opted for an IP address that has a very small chance of colliding with anything out there.

On my Android device I want to have a **working internet connection** and **access to my bridge** at the **same time**. This is why I want to add a this static route.

Some more details on my configuration

```
shell@msm8916_64:/ $ busybox ip route get 10.245.245.253
10.245.245.253 via 172.17.2.1 dev wlan0  src 172.17.2.245
```

And some more

```
1|shell@msm8916_64:/ $ busybox ip rule
0:      from all lookup local
10000:  from all fwmark 0xc0000 lookup 99
13000:  from all fwmark 0x10063 lookup 97
13000:  from all fwmark 0x10069 lookup 236
14000:  from all lookup 236
15000:  from all lookup 99
16000:  from all lookup 98
17000:  from all lookup 97
19000:  from all fwmark 0x69 lookup 236
22000:  from all lookup 236
23000:  from all lookup main
32000:  from all unreachable
```

And some more:

```
shell@msm8916_64:/ # ip route list table main
10.245.245.252/30 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.245.245.254
172.17.2.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.2.245  metric 304

shell@msm8916_64:/ # ip route list table local
broadcast 10.245.245.252 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.245.245.254
local 10.245.245.254 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope host  src 10.245.245.254
broadcast 10.245.245.255 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.245.245.254
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1
broadcast 172.17.2.0 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.2.245
local 172.17.2.245 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope host  src 172.17.2.245
broadcast 172.17.2.255 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.2.245

1|shell@msm8916_64:/ # iptables -t main -n -L
iptables v1.4.20: can't initialize iptables table `main': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

Comment: You used commands to just show your network configuration. Why did you expect that it would help in any way? I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Sorry the wording is confusing. The first code snippet shows command that I have tried. The second code snippet shows the current configuration. The third code snippet shows i can ping my ip in that subnet. What I am trying to achieve is ping the bridge at 10.245.245.253. But as you can see with the traceroute command it doesnt work

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: You have a second IP address. Look at `wlan0`. Your problem isn't the IP address. Have you connected to the bridge in any way previously? Are you sure wireless works on your device?

Comment: It's funny that traceroute shows `172.17.2.1` as first hop. Does your busybox support `ip route get 10.245.245.253`? Anything in `iptables` or policy routing tables (`ip rule`)?

Comment: I will include more general information about my problem to encourage alternative ideas.

The current setup works. I have a working internet on my Android device (PC in the picture). I can ping my gateway 172.17.2.1. If i change IP settings of the PC i can also ping the bridge at (10.245.245.253).

I will update the anwser with the ip route get 10.245.245.253 response and ip rule

Comment: @Centimane If i had a working second IP on that interface the traceroute would no try to go to the gateway. This is why I am trying to debug the situation but have ran out of options.

Comment: @MartinTramšak I'm wondering why you'd even want the DHCP address? If you just take the `10.245.245.254` address, and add a route to your other network `ip route add 172.17.2.0/24 dev wlan0 via 10.245.245.253` you should be fine. Your current setup emulates 3 subnets, when you only need 2.

Comment: @Centimane maybe you should read my extended question where I expand on the reasons. The wireless bridge doesnt know which network it will be plugged in. Furthermore I want the wireless client to be in the subnet of the default gateway regardless of its IP settings whoch are not known in advance. This question is a specific scenario which my device (the wireless bridge) might encounter.

Comment: You have a rather complicated routing setup there, with 4 additional routing tables and extra routing rules for marks set by the firewall. This is almost certainly the problem. So look at the exta tables (`ip route list table 99` etc.), look at the firewall rules (`iptables`), figure out what is going on.

Comment: And guys: the question is completely clear. I really don't understand the close votes.

Comment: Without the extra routing rules, this works just fine on my setup here. Please could you include a dump of your policy routing table rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a rather complicated routing setup there, with four additional routing tables and extra routing rules for marks set by the firewall. This is almost certainly the problem. So look at the exta tables (`ip route list table 99` etc.), look at the firewall rules (`iptables -t table_name -n -L` for all `table_name`), then figure out what is going on.

**Edit**

Routing tables and firewall tables (`iptables`) are completely different, so `iptables -t main -n -L` makes no sense because `main` is a routing table, not a firewall table.

Please edit question with output of `ip route list table 97`, `ip route list table 98` etc. including `99` and `236`. Also with output of `iptables -t filter -n -L`, `iptables -t nat -n -L` etc. including `mangle`, `raw` and any other table that may be mentioned in the rules. If the output is too long, put all in a pastebin and link to it.

There are plenty of tutorials on the web for `iptables` and policy routing if you want to do some reading. But even if we figure out what prevents the second address from becoming the source address, the more difficult task is to figure out *why* all these rules are there, what the person making these rules wanted to achieve, and how we can change the rules to make the second address work without breaking other stuff.

So if you are happy with the answer "because some sort of firewall rules prevent it", we can also leave it at that. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your response and I think you are right. But this routing policy is a little bit over my head. I am using command ip route list table <table name> and all are empty excpet local and main. I've included them in the question. Iptables tells me that the tables do not exist.

Comment: I will check the output of iptables commands, but conc erning the ip route list <table> all are empty except for the main and local which i included in the question